# How to import data from an excel file for subtype cluster tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables called Products, Books and Pens. Books and Pens are of Products kind. and each row of Books table and Pens table has one to one relationship with Product table. I'm using subtype cluster relationships for designing my tables.And for implementing my design I'm using the below query. However, my problem is when importing an excel that has data relevant to Books, the sql server shows an error to me which is about the column productType in Books that it is read only and thus I can not import data to that column. I appreciate if anyone can solve my problem.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
(
     SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     ProductType CHAR(1) NOT NULL
         CHECK (ProductType IN ('B', 'P'  /* Book, PEN */)),
     Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE (SKU, ProductType)
);

CREATE TABLE Books
(
    SKU INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductType AS ISNULL(CAST(‘B’ AS CHAR(1)), ”) PERSISTED,
    Pages SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (SKU,ProductType) REFERENCES Products (SKU,ProductType)
);
```

Comment: Please share the excel file.

Comment: Please can you post a sample of the data that is causing the problem as text please.

Comment: Thank you very mich for the replys. I could handle the problem without the need to change the above query.